# Where are the t-values in my pairwise comparisons?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

I have data from a study with three conditions. The independent variable was within-subjects and within-items.

I did an F1 and F2 analysis (= twice a repeated measures ANOVA) on the averages, by subject (the participants) and by item (the words). I checked/corrected for sphericity and the means do differ significantly.

Now I want to know how the three conditions differ from one another. I have a "Pairwise Comparisons" box and p-values (I checked "Bonferroni" when doing the analyses). But I do not have t-values.

How can I know my corresponding t-values? Or should I do some paired-samples t-tests? If so, what does this "Pairwise Comparisons" box tell me?

Screenshot of the "PC" box:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your 2nd sentence, and also what you mean by "item."  Also, for people to interpret your software program's output, it would be best if you could show it.

Comment: I didn't want to go in too deep, because I think it's irrelevant. But is it better now? I added a screenshot as well.

Comment: I am not familiar with the software but if Std. Error ist the standard error of the estimate of the differences in means as I expect, the t-value is just the difference divided through the std. error (about 3.08 in the first row).

Comment: Someone check me on this, as I am not certain but I believe that within GLM options, the pairwise comparisons are reporting paired sample t-tests (with adjustments as requested). To get the actual df and test statistic you have to run a paired sample t-test. I guess the comparisons are helpful in that it will adjust your p and your confidence intervals?

Comment: You must divide the Mean difference(I-J) by the Standard Error. The result is your t value.

Answer (score 1):

Bonferroni is a bound on the familywise error rate (FWER).  It just involves the p-values of the individual tests.  There is no test statistic for it. Basically if you are doing $k$ tests and all the $p$-values are less than $p$ Bonferroni gives $k\cdot p$ as the upper bound on FWER. It has the advantage of being general (not requiring any specific assumptions).  But the disadvantage is that it is a conservative upper bound and will not be useful unless $p$ is small enough to make $k\cdot p$ relatively small.  It is possible for $k\cdot p$ to be greater than 1.  There are many other procedures that can be used that are not so conservative and some just involve the individual $p$-values.  Examples are bootstrap and permutation adjusted p-values.  You can find this in the resampling book for multiple comparisons by Westfall and Young.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is an useful comment on Bonferroni but should be IMHO (in scope of this question) a comment and not an answer.

Comment: This downvoting on the basis of whether or not you think my answer is an answer to the question is ridiculous. This is a question whose answer is that there are no t-values because there are no t tests involved in the Bonferroni bound.  Explaining the Bonferroni bound answers the question because it shows why there are no t-values.  You should take back your downvote Erik.

Comment: Michael, some caution is probably in order. Voting is anonymous and not necessarily correlated with commenting. For example, some of the posts of yours that I have commented on have ended up later with downvotes. I find people tend to comment first without downvoting or even without even intending to ever do so.

Comment: I find also that our site in particular appears to be remarkably devoid of capricious or malicious behavior. In large part this is a testament to the management of our three outstanding moderators and also to the professionalism of the bulk of our contributors. If you are finding yourself the target of persistent downvoting it may be a sign that one or more community members have reservations about some pattern of use. If you have concerns yourself, I'd suggest either contacting the mods privately or addressing the issue on our meta site.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I flagged it in the hope it would be converted to a comment. Apparently, the moderator disagreed which is of course fine. Note that any downvote on my part would have pointless if it actually had been converted to a comment. The downvote was from someone else.

Comment: BTW, I still don't think it answers the question. The original p-values that Bonferroni operates on still come from a t-statistic.

Comment: The Bonferroni bound doesn't care what test was used to generate the p-values it only cares what the p-values are. He asked three questions.  I answered one of them namely "If so, what does this "Pairwise Comparisons" box tell me?"  Can't I choose to answer the question that I can give an answer to? Maybe the question about t values is legitimate since the p-values probably come from pairwise t tests.

Comment: But only the p-value matters for Bonferroni.  Mien doesn't seem to know that or realize that the t-values have no relevance to this test.  I think he might be thinking that there is a test statistic that is used to get the adjusted p-value and that it is a function of the individual t-values.  But there isn't.

Comment: I think he is thinking along the lines of say Tukey's LSD test which does have a test statistic and a p-value associated with it.  There is no need to switch to paired t tests. So the question I answered is the only one that has real important and would help this pure confused guy understand what is going on.  I should get an up vote for that not a downvote!

Comment: @MichaelChernick thanks for helping :) But I don't think you've answered my question. My supervisor said that I had to report the t-values as well, but I don't have any. I was just wondering whether I had to do t-tests to know the t-values. You also mentioned that Bonferroni uses p-values. How does it get those?

Comment: I answered part of the question.  Whether reporting t-values is important is a matter of opinion.  I just object to people downvoting me because I only answered part of the question.  Regarding Cardinals remarks I disagree,  I didn't know who downvoted me and just explained why I objected to the downvote,  Erik volunteered that he downvoted and was nice enough to give his reason.  My further comments about the downvote was not just intended for private debate.  It raises the issue of how one judges whether or not a question gets answered

Comment: @Mien  The p-values that are used for Bonferroni are the raw p-values from the individual tests.  As Erik pointed out the t-values led to the determination of the raw p-values.  My point is that the Bonferroni adjustment can be applied to any tests wher p-values are given and not just t-tests.

Comment: I think the answer to getting the t-values depends on what software package you use.  So if you specify that, some expert in that package may be able to help you,

Comment: @cardinal Is downvoting something that the site encourages if you don't like the tone of an answer rather than just the content?  I hope that people here don't use popularity as a criterion for upvoting or downvoting.  That was what voting on subscriber book reviews degenerated into on amazon where reviewer get rankings based in favorable and nonfavorable votes.  I intend to behave professionally and follow the site rules. Being new (a member for just 3 days now) I am just having a hard time learning and understanding all of them.

Comment: I did not volunteer that I downvoted, in fact I clearly stated that I did, in fact, not downvote your answer. I had not and still haven't voted on it at all. The tip regarding the software package is good, a screenshot of the settings of the multiple comparison would also help.

Comment: Hi, Michael. Here are a few brief remarks. (**1**) Note that my first comment is alluding to the fact that one should not assume that receiving a comment and a downvote are strongly positively correlated. In fact, I think they tend to be negatively correlated, unfortunately. (**2**) Note that Erik *explicitly* states in a later comment that, indeed, he did *not* downvote your post. (**3**) Downvoting is a tricky thing, I've found. It *should* (in my opinion) be pretty much exclusively reserved for either erroneous answers or obviously unconstructive behavior. But, it is a subjective thing...

Comment: ...and so each person is left to their own devices and judgment when making such a decision. (**4**) Your comments are interesting and important, but are more "meta" comments regarding the site. If you have concerns or want to discuss it further, it's probably better to post a question regarding this on our [meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com) and tag it as `discussion`. (**5**) It takes everyone a little time to get adjusted to the way the site works. We all went through a learning curve. I'm glad you are asking questions and seeking to learn more about the community's culture. Cheers.

Comment: I misunderstood Erik because he was defending the downvote giving a rationale for it.  Sorry for the misattribution.  Frnakly, the complexity of this system is some what of a turnoff to me.  But it is a great group so I will try to perservere.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this quote helps you. 
"As you see in the output below, the table titled "Contrast Coefficients (L' Matrix)" shows the coding scheme that was used for each comparison.  The table entitled "Contrast Results (K Matrix)" shows the results of the various contrasts.  In our example, the difference between level 1 of race and level 4 of race is statistically significant.  You will notice that the contrast estimate is the difference between the mean for the dependent variable for the first level minus the mean of the dependent variable for the omitted level.  In other words, the mean for level 1 minus the mean for level 4 which is 46.4583 - 54.0552 = -7.597.  The row labeled "Sig." is .000, indicating that this difference is significant, and this is followed by a confidence interval for the difference. The next part of the table compares level 2 of race and level 4 of race and shows that this difference is not statistically significant and the next part of the table shows the difference between level 3 of race and level 4 of race is statistically significant. You might note that while the significance ("Sig.") is given for each of these tests, there is no "t" value, but you could obtain this by dividing the "Contrast Estimate" by the "Std. Error", i.e., -7.597 / 1.989.".

Thus, if you have values for contrast estimate and std erro, you can calculate t value yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get the quote from?

Answer (score 0):

The p value in the output is for the associated z statistic: mean difference divided by the standard error. So, it's a z value, not a t value. If you look up the p value associated with the z value, that's what you'll see in the SPSS output. Here are the steps if you want to verify what I'm saying:

1. In the SPSS output for pairwise comparisons, take the mean difference and divide it by its standard error. That is your z value
2. Go here (or somewhere similar): https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/normaldistribution.aspx
3. Enter the z value in the calculator to get your associated p value. That should be the p value you see in the SPSS output. For the life of me I don't know why they don't just display the value of the z statistic.